# How to read a csv without separators?

Tags: python, csv

i need to read a csv, but it's without separator in the columns and column titles. There is a space and when I use `pd.read_csv(url, sep='\s+', header=None, engine='python', error_bad_lines=False)`

[image]

i've take a lot of organization problems like that:

[image]

How can I read this?
Help me, please!

Comment: Looks like tab-separated to me.

Comment: If it is tab separated, you can use `sep='\t'`to split only on the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it space-delimited or tab-delimited?  I would try `sep='\t'` and see if that works better.